# Passing information from asp.net to server using JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

What I need to do is passing a piece of information (anything e.g. a  "hello world") to a method on server (C#) from asp.net page using JSON.

I have a general idea of JSON and also asp.net. I found a blog and an example on CodeProject however, they are all in MVC and I'm new to MVC.

Can somebody give me some direction (baby steps) so I can learn this?

Thanks

Comment: JSON is just data (JavaScript Object Notation). You don't send 'via JSON' you 'send JSON via' something else.

Comment: I should say it was a typo ... right but again need to know how to pass json to back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Just direction only. You can use the free course (10 modules) by Scot Allen to learn MVC. This is an excellent course. I think you will like it. http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight

Comment: It is a good start ... giving me some ideas where to start. Thank you